# Jquery scroll and position animation: jittery and skips in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I have built a relatively simple website with scrolling images with captions. I'm using jQuery to animate scrolling to the next image every time a timer fires. It works well except for the first image and transition, which in Chrome jitters even before any animations have run (I think during loading of other images), and then the first scroll animation makes it jump to somewhere seemingly arbitrary. After these problems it runs fine. In Safari it works fine.

The code is here on the live site at www.rafecopeland.co.nz (can also write it out here if preferred? don't know the etiquette here yet)

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Rafe

Comment: You should post the pertinent code along with your question, yes. And it works just fine for me, do you have the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: Scrolling large images using JS is memory-intensive. Your images are 2.5x as big as they need to be for that page (open in new window...). As your browser reaches it's memory limit, it rerenders the scrolling page less often, thus the glitchyness. CSS3 transitions might be more efficient. You could also try reducing the size of the images.

Comment: Thanks @WanderingDigital, they are indeed large images, I will size them down to see if that works.

Comment: And thanks for the tip @Zeaklous, will do in the future